# C# How to find specific item and it's related items from list

Tags: c#, list, find, tree-traversal

I have the following class

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastItem { get; set; }
}
```

Let say I have the following model and I want to find specific item by Id and it's related item Ids. In this scenario I want to find Id of item9 and it's related item Ids.

Result should contains 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

[image: Model]

I get the list of my model from database and I simulated it in the code block like this

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item
    {
        Id = 1,
        ParentId = 0,
        Content = "item1",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 2,
        ParentId = 1,
        Content = "item2",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 3,
        ParentId = 1,
        Content = "item3",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 4,
        ParentId = 1,
        Content = "item4",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 5,
        ParentId = 2,
        Content = "item5",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 6,
        ParentId = 5,
        Content = "item6",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 7,
        ParentId = 5,
        Content = "item7",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 8,
        ParentId = 6,
        Content = "item8",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 9,
        ParentId = 7,
        Content = "item9",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 10,
        ParentId = 9,
        Content = "item10",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 11,
        ParentId = 9,
        Content = "item11",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 12,
        ParentId = 11,
        Content = "item12",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 13,
        ParentId = 11,
        Content = "item13",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 14,
        ParentId = 11,
        Content = "item14",
        IsLastItem = true
    }
};
```

Comment: If you want to use your data like a tree structure then why not actually use a tree structure instead of a list?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad: I get that model from database. That's why I have it as a flat model.

Comment: If this data is used extensively, it might be worth looking into transforming it into a tree structure. It's at least worth looking into. Here's one example I found with a quick search: [Flat Data to Hierarchical Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949442/flat-data-to-hierarchical-model-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive method

```
// Start finding the base item to start the recursive search
Item x = items.Where(i => i.Id == 9).FirstOrDefault();
List<Item> found = Search(items, x);

// Insert the starting item at the first position (Add is also good but...)
found.Insert(0, x);



public List<Item> Search(List<Item> list, Item parent)
{
    // Prepare the list to return...
    List<Item> found = new List<Item>();
    if (parent != null)
    {
        // Search all the items that have the parent passed
        List<Item> temp = list.Where(x => x.ParentId == parent.Id).ToList();
        // Add the list to the return variable
        found.AddRange(temp);
        // For each child of this parent look for their childs
        foreach(Item x in temp)
            found.AddRange(Search(list, x));
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq, something like below should get you started...

```
var parent = items.First(x => x.Content == "item9");
var children = items.Where(x => x.Id == parent.Id);
```

Comment: Note that this would only find its direct children, not the child of its children.

Comment: @GuntherFox is correct, I missed that part of the graphic.  In order to get the children of children you would need to implement a recursive method.  It sounds like the database model could be updated to use navigation properties and `.Include()` to make this easier.